# Extracting integer from a string in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have a string in this pattern:

`2(some_substring) -> 3(some_other_substring)`

Now these number can be anything.

I think this [answer](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Extract_numbers_from_an_alpha_numeric_string#Tcl) would solve the problem. But it gives all the integers in one variable. I want them to be in different variables, so that I can analyze them. Can we split it? But Splitting would cause problem:

If the the numbers are not single-digit, then the splitting will be erroneous.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a variation of this: instead of removing the non-digit characters, you can extract all digit characters into a list:

```
set text {2(some_substring) -> 3(some_other_substring)}
set numbers [regexp -all -inline -- {[0-9]+} $text]
puts $numbers
# => 2 3
```

And to get each number, you can use `lindex`:

```
puts [lindex $numbers 0]
# => 2
```

Or in versions 8.5 and later, you can use `lassign` to assign them to specific variable names:

```
lassign $numbers first second
puts $first
# => 2
puts $second
# => 3
```

---

In `regexp -all -inline -- {[0-9]+} $text`, `-all` extract all the matches, `-inline` puts the matches into a list, `--` ends the options, `[0-9]+` matches at least one integer.

Comment: can i use:

`set no1 [lindex $numbers 0]`

`set no2 [lindex $numbers 1]` ?

Comment: yep that worked.. i can `set` them like that too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To extend Jerry's answer, in case digits can appear within the parentheses, a regular expression to only extract digits that are immediately followed by an open parenthesis is: `{\d+(=\()}`

```
% set text {2(some_6substring) -> 3(some_other_5substring)}
2(some_6substring) -> 3(some_other_5substring)
% lassign [regexp -all -inline {\d+(?=\()} $text] first second
% set first
2
% set second
3
```

This assumes that you don't have nested parentheses.